# Jquery Sortable with Drag and Drop Indent

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table and I am using Jquery-UI Sortable
what I am trying to achieve is 
when I perform drag and drop to the  table row and when I am dropping it should be indented or added with some margin to that respective row
for e.g
If I have a table as
[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThb8.jpg)

now I drag and drop say row no #1 to row no #3 
1. it should ask me the confirmation (are you sure? you want to drop here?")
2. I want if the user agrees with the drop and that row should be added with some margin or indented towards right

Here's the JS Code

```html
$(function() {
    
    var fixHelper = function (e, ui) {
        ui.children().each(function () {
            $(this).width($(this).width());
        });
        return ui;
    };
    $("#tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        placeholder: "placeholder",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            ui.placeholder.addClass('placeholder-sub');
        },
        sort: function (event, ui) {
            var pos;
            pos = ui.position.left + 20;

        }

    });


});
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>Larry</td>
            <td>the Bird</td>
            <td>twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am currently using Jquery/Jquery UI and Bootstrap css
jquery  v1.12.4
Jquery ui-  jQuery UI - v1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

I think sortable doesn't have any undo-last-drop function, so you'll need to save the order before dragging and restore it if the user cancels. As for confirmation functionality, you should check [jquery confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

Comment: Not exactly I want to drag and drop the Row below it and I want that row to be indented. I do understand the jquery confirmation box. so can you help in the first part suppose I am dragging any row and now I had decided to dropped it over it and once dropped I just want it should be indented towards the right or some margin I am currently using with table tr and td if it can be achieved any other way please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use receive function for this as below:

```
        receive: function( event, ui ) {                  
            if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                 ui.sender.sortable("cancel");
            } else {
                 ui.item.after(ui.item.data('items'));
            }                
        },
```

It will show confirmation box and then on ok, will allow user to have dropped element. And for marging/indenting, you need to apply css on each dropped element via parent container. Hope it helps you.